# Error:Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'navigationVersion'

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, android-safe-args

I get this error when make two changes
first, add the following dependency in my build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$version_kotlin"
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
```

Second add the line to my build.gradle(module) file

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your navigationVresion like below

```
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

currently, you used a variable like `navigationVersion` but that variable is not defined in your Gradle file.